# GTK dropdown calendar widget?

Tags: calendar, gtk

I've been having trouble with creating a dropdown GTK calendar widget in an app of mine.

**Objectives:**

Basically I wanted to have a text combo-box where you can type in the date such as 2011/02/01 for example and it would autoformat the date.  This part is not a problem, the other part which is the drop down calendar aspect where you can click on the dropdown button next to the combo-box and it drops down into a calendar in which you can select the date.

**Problems/semi-solutions:**

I've spent some work hacking at this with Ruby GTK (Gnome bindings really) and below is some of the solutions that I've came up with.

1. Basically I created a textbox, then created a button and gave it the "down arrow" to simulate a dropdown button for a combo-box and it looks alright, not the greatest thing in the world.
2. For the actual calendar widget, I would create a borderless/titleless dialog box and embed the calendar widget in it and place it just under the text box where the dropdown combo-box list would appear.
3. It would be dismissed when the user selects a date.

However there are several problems with the above solution that I've came up with which is:

1. The borderless/titleless dialog box still creates something that is being displayed on the taskbar...
2. If the user press say "ctrl+q" to quit the application, since the calendar widget has focus the key-binding never makes it to the parent window.
3. If i move the parent window, the calendar widget is stuck there floating in the air.
4. If i click somewhere else or type the date into the textbox, the calendar widget does not disappear, I have to pick a date from the calendar widget...

So in short I would like some advice or suggestion on how to do a proper/better way of doing a calendar dropdown widget?  I would prefer to keep this purely in GTK without additional widgets like from Gnome, etc...

Comment: Problem 1 might happen if the dialog doesn't have a parent window. Not sure about ruby, but in c++, a dialog's constructor accepts a parent window as a parameter. When I pass this parameter, the dialog isn't displayed in the taskbar.

Comment: I also had to make a calendar widget once, and had all problems 2-4. I finally worked around 2 and 4 by adding Accept and Cancel buttons. At least it explicitly showed the user a way of closing the calendar. Didn't really had time to do something about problem 3. I guess it could be done catching some motion event from the parent window and moving the calendar accordingly (using "motion-notify-event" perhaps, someone correct me). That's all advice I can offer I'm afraid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The combo box takes a `GtkListStore` for its dropdown menu. You could implement a custom `GtkCellRenderer` that renders a date as a `GtkCalendar` in its cell, then just have one item (the date) in the list store. When you drop down the combo box, the calendar will appear, the user can select a date, and then you can read the date from your list store.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea! But implementing a GtkCellRenderer that renders a date as a GtkCalendar sounds pretty intimidating to someone unfamiliar with GTK (how do you "render" a _control_ in a cell renderer?), so some example code would have been nice...

Comment: Well, it is intimidating, to be honest -- too complicated to post some example code here. I've been wanting to write a tutorial on how to write custom cell renderers for some time, but I haven't found the time.